# Dataframe within dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider this example:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10,var1=LETTERS[1:10],var2=LETTERS[6:15])

fun.split <- function(x) tolower(as.character(x))
df$new.letters <- apply(df[ ,2:3],2,fun.split)

df$new.letters.var1
#NULL

colnames(df)
# [1] "id"          "var1"        "var2"        "new.letters"

df$new.letters
#       var1 var2
# [1,]  "a"  "f" 
# [2,]  "b"  "g" 
# [3,]  "c"  "h" 
# [4,]  "d"  "i" 
# [5,]  "e"  "j" 
# [6,]  "f"  "k" 
# [7,]  "g"  "l" 
# [8,]  "h"  "m" 
# [9,]  "i"  "n" 
# [10,] "j"  "o"
```

Would be someone so kind and explain what is going on here? A new dataframe within dataframe?

I expected this:

```
colnames(df)
# id var1 var2 new.letters.var1 new.letters.var2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is because you assigned a single new column to a 2 column `matrix` output by `apply`.  So, the result will be a `matrix` in a single column.  You can convert it back to normal data.frame with

```
 do.call(data.frame, df)
```

A more straightforward method will be to assign 2 columns and I use `lapply` instead of `apply` as there can be cases where the columns are of different classes.  `apply` returns a `matrix` and with mixed class, the columns will be 'character' class.  But, `lapply` gets the output in a `list` and preserves the `class`

```
df[paste0('new.letters', names(df)[2:3])] <- lapply(df[2:3], fun.split)
```

Answer (score 7):

@akrun solved 90% of my problem. But I had data.frames buried within data.frames, buried within data.frames and so on, without knowing the depth to which this was happening.

In this case, I thought sharing my recursive solution might be helpful to others searching this thread as I was:

```
    unnest_dataframes <- function(x) {

        y <- do.call(data.frame, x)

        if("data.frame" %in% sapply(y, class)) unnest_dataframes(y)

        y

    }

    new_data <- unnest_dataframes(df)
```

Although this itself sometimes has problems and it can be helpful to separate all columns of class "data.frame" from the original data set then cbind() it back together like so:

```
  # Find all columns that are data.frame
  # Assuming your data frame is stored in variable 'y'
  data.frame.cols <- unname(sapply(y, function(x) class(x) == "data.frame"))
  z <- y[, !data.frame.cols]

  # All columns of class "data.frame"
  dfs <- y[, data.frame.cols]

  # Recursively unnest each of these columns
  unnest_dataframes <- function(x) {
    y <- do.call(data.frame, x)
    if("data.frame" %in% sapply(y, class)) {
        unnest_dataframes(y)
    } else {
        cat('Nested data.frames successfully unpacked\n')
      }
    y
  }

  df2 <- unnest_dataframes(dfs)

  # Combine with original data
  all_columns <- cbind(z, df2)
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case R doesn't behave like one would expect but maybe if we dig deeper we can solve it. What is a data frame? as Norman Matloff says in his book (chapter 5):

> a data frame is a list, with the components of that list being
>   equal-length vectors

The following code might be useful to understand.

```
class(df$new.letters)
[1] "matrix"


str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ var1       : Factor w/ 10 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ var2       : Factor w/ 10 levels "F","G","H","I",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ new.letters: chr [1:10, 1:2] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "var1" "var2"
```

Maybe the reason why it looks strange is in the print methods. Consider this:

```
colnames(df$new.letters)
[1] "var1" "var2"
```

maybe there must something in the print methods that combine the sub-names of objects and display them all.

For example here the vectors that constitute the `df` are:

```
names(df)
[1] "id"          "var1"        "var2"        "new.letters"
```

but in this case the vector `new.letters` also has a dim attributes (in fact it is a matrix) were dimensions have names `var1` and `var1` too. See this code:

```
attributes(df$new.letters)
$dim
[1] 10  2

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
NULL

$dimnames[[2]]
[1] "var1" "var2"
```

but when we print we see all of them like they were separated vectors (and so columns of the data.frame!).

#### Edit: Print methods

Just for curiosity in order to improve this question I looked inside the methods of the `print` functions:

```
methods(print)
```

The previous code produces a very long list of methods for the generic function `print` but there is no one for data.frame. The one that looks for data frame (but I am sure there is a more technically way to find out that) is  `listof`.

```
getS3method("print", "listof")
function (x, ...) 
{
    nn <- names(x)
    ll <- length(x)
    if (length(nn) != ll) 
        nn <- paste("Component", seq.int(ll))
    for (i in seq_len(ll)) {
        cat(nn[i], ":\n")
        print(x[[i]], ...)
        cat("\n")
    }
    invisible(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x101afe1c8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Maybe I am wrong but It seems to me that in this code there might be useful informations about why that happens, specifically when the `if (length(nn) != ll)` is stated.