# How can I fully extract all elements into a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I retrieve some data from an API and convert it to a flat structure.

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2019-11-25/2019-11-26"

raw_original <- GET(url)

raw <- rawToChar(raw_original$content)

raw <- fromJSON(raw)

api_extr <- do.call("rbind", lapply(raw, data.frame))
```

At first, all seems well (a 5-column data frame):

```
> head(api_extr)
               from                to intensity.forecast intensity.actual intensity.index
1 2019-11-24T23:30Z 2019-11-25T00:00Z                210              200        moderate
2 2019-11-25T00:00Z 2019-11-25T00:30Z                199              200        moderate
3 2019-11-25T00:30Z 2019-11-25T01:00Z                200              198        moderate
4 2019-11-25T01:00Z 2019-11-25T01:30Z                204              189        moderate
5 2019-11-25T01:30Z 2019-11-25T02:00Z                199              191        moderate
6 2019-11-25T02:00Z 2019-11-25T02:30Z                192              193        moderate
```

However, one of the columns (`intensity`) is in fact a data frame which contains three further columns.

```
> str(api_extr)
'data.frame':   49 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ from     : chr  "2019-11-24T23:30Z" "2019-11-25T00:00Z" "2019-11-25T00:30Z" "2019-11-25T01:00Z" ...
 $ to       : chr  "2019-11-25T00:00Z" "2019-11-25T00:30Z" "2019-11-25T01:00Z" "2019-11-25T01:30Z" ...
 $ intensity:'data.frame':  49 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ forecast: int  210 199 200 204 199 192 191 194 197 192 ...
  ..$ actual  : int  200 200 198 189 191 193 197 193 193 194 ...
  ..$ index   : chr  "moderate" "moderate" "moderate" "moderate" ...
```

I would expect the data frame to have five columns whereas instead it only has three.

At first glance this may seem insignificant, but the problems will start when it comes to working with the data (i.e. plotting it).

How can I achieve five columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe within dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896605/dataframe-within-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the URL directly to `fromJSON` and flatten the result in a single step.

```
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2019-11-25/2019-11-26"
df <-fromJSON(url, flatten = TRUE)[[1]]

str(df)

'data.frame':   49 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ from              : chr  "2019-11-24T23:30Z" "2019-11-25T00:00Z" "2019-11-25T00:30Z" "2019-11-25T01:00Z" ...
 $ to                : chr  "2019-11-25T00:00Z" "2019-11-25T00:30Z" "2019-11-25T01:00Z" "2019-11-25T01:30Z" ...
 $ intensity.forecast: int  210 199 200 204 199 192 191 194 197 192 ...
 $ intensity.actual  : int  200 200 198 189 191 193 197 193 193 194 ...
 $ intensity.index   : chr  "moderate" "moderate" "moderate" "moderate" ...
```

Comment: Not quite what I was asking, but this is actually a much more efficient way of handling the job in hand and a good solution also (the result is what I was looking for, thus making it a valid solution).